# Plot BarChart and fixing the bars

Tags: plotting, matrix, legending, charts, histograms

I have 3 problems plotting the amplitudes of eigenvectors of a matrix `H` vertically (column).

e.g.
`H={{1, 1, 1}, {1, -0.5, -1}, {0.5, 0.7, -0.7}}`

***First Problem***

I tried to use `BarChart`, but I noticed that the range has been scaled (all the graphs do not start from 1 in the x-axis). It's ranged from -1 to 1 in y-axis and from 1 to `n` (`n` is the dimension of the matrix `H` or the length of `H`).

***Second Problem***

I want to reduce the giant bars and make them thinner, and to join the them by a sinusoidal line which should from the top the every bar.

***Third Problem***

I want to label each graph with "Eigenvectors-i", where `i` is number from 1 to `n`.

```
BarChart[{{1, 1, 1}, {0.5, 0.7, -0.7}, {0, 0.1, 1}, {0, 0.1, 1}},
  ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Dashed], BarSpacing -> 10,
  ChartLayout -> "Column", PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {-1, 1.1}}]
```

Comment: Do you want something like this `{{Table[Framed@
     BarChart[H[[i]], BarSpacing -> 4, 
      PlotRange -> {{0.75, 3.25}, {-1, 1}}, AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, 
      PlotLabel -> "Eigenvectors-" <> ToString[i]], {i, 
     3}]}} // TableForm` ? I don't understand the  "a sinusoidal line which should from the top the every bar" part of the question however. Should the chart of {1,1,1} show something like $\cos(2 \pi*x)$ which passes through all the bar tops?

Comment: Please stay responsive to comments.

Comment: @ydd @Syed I used your code , it works but I couldn't Label it , even thought if i'm choosin {1,2,3} as the x-axis, the label goes to the center which obscure the negative bars . So I think of Labelin only the bottom plot and addin legends.  ```H = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, -0.5, -1, 0}, {0.5, -0.7, 0, -0.7}, {0, 0,  1, -1}}; {{Table[Framed@ BarChart[H[[i]], BarSpacing -> 4, PlotRange -> {{0.79, 4.25}, {-1, 1}},ChartStyle -> {Black, Brown, Brown, Black},AxesOrigin -> {1, 0},ChartLabels -> {{"Array " <> ToString[i]}, {s, 2, 3, s}},PlotLabel -> "Ev" <> ToString[i]], {i,Length[H]}]}} // TableForm```

Comment: @MedCh I probably should used the `Frame` option instead of `Framed` with my example, sorry. With this, the `ChartLabels` are now on the bottom frame:
`Table[BarChart[H[[i]], BarSpacing -> 4, 
   PlotRange -> {{0.79, 4.25}, {-1.1, 1.1}}, 
   ChartStyle -> {Black, Brown, Brown, Black}, AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, 
   ChartLabels -> {s, 2, 3, s}, PlotLabel -> "Ev" <> ToString[i], 
   Frame -> True], {i, Length[H]}] // TableForm`
Is this closer to what your looking for?

Comment: @ydd yes That's what I wanted ,Thank you for your efforts.